# Error Undefined Variable alternative on codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I found this error type of error on my view file as shown below.Please help me to solve out this error. I am greatful for solving this promblem. I am waiting for correct answer
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: alternative

Filename: views/all_investor_relation.php

Line Number: 47

```
<div class="tabs-left">


                            <?php

                if($out){
                foreach($out as $row=>$value){

                    $paths=base_url().'uploads/investor_relation/';

                    $image=$value['docpath'];

                    $title=$value['title'];

                    $imageso="<a href='$paths$image' title='$title' target='_blank'>$title</a>";

                    $content="<tr $alternative>

                                         <td>".$i."</td><!-- this is line number 47-->

                                        <td>".$imageso."</td>

             }
                echo $content;
                }

                else{

                    echo "<tr><td colspan='4'>Page not Available Available.</td></tr>";

                }

                ?>           

</div>
```

Comment: post your controller code so we can find where $alternative come

Comment: **$content = "<tr $alternative>** what does it means

Comment: it means $alternative come from controller side.Because he is not assign anything to $alternative in view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the variable $alternative in

```
                                    $content="<tr $alternative>

                                     <td>".$i."</td><!-- this is line number 47-->

                                    <td>".$imageso."</td>
```

And Try this code

```
$content="<tr><td>".$imageso."</td>";
```

Answer (score 3):

It is happening because you have not define $alternative anywhere, please find below the updated code.

```
<div class="tabs-left">


                            <?php

                if($out){
                $alternative = ""
                foreach($out as $row=>$value){

                    $paths=base_url().'uploads/investor_relation/';

                    $image=$value['docpath'];

                    $title=$value['title'];

                    $imageso="<a href='$paths$image' title='$title' target='_blank'>$title</a>";

                    $content="<tr $alternative>

                                         <td>".$i."</td><!-- this is line number 47-->

                                        <td>".$imageso."</td>

             }
                echo $content;
                }

                else{

                    echo "<tr><td colspan='4'>Page not Available Available.</td></tr>";

                }

                ?>           

</div>
```

Currently I have put $alternative = "" inside if condition, You can modified as per your usage, Most probably I think you want to use it to apply alternate class to , something like "odd" and "even" class.

Answer (score 1):

if your variable $alternative is coming from controller then plz share controller code other wise remove $alternative from this line `$content="<tr $alternative>........`